# What do the characteristics of a PDE represent?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can anybody provide a good intuitive explanation of what the characteristics of a PDE represent?

What does it mean for the initial data to "propagate" along the characteristic curves?

I understand how to find the characteristic curves of a PDE, but I have trouble understanding their physical meaning.

Comment: See e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86570/explaining-the-method-of-characteristics