# I don't understand the 'idea' behind the method of characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Below is an image of my lecture notes explaining the idea behind the method of characteristics for quasilinear first order PDEs.

[image]

[image]

However I don't understand how the curve $C_s$ is defined and how it translates into the graph $Gr_u$. How does $C_s$ 'start' on the initial curve if there is no $f(s)$ or $g(s)$ in the equation for $C_s$? What does $x(t;s)$ mean, does that mean (say for the $x$ term) that for fixed $s$ one starts at $x(s-\epsilon_s)$ and finishes at $x(s+\epsilon_s)$? If so what is this 'function' $x$?

Thanks, I would really appreciate someone explaining this to me! :

Comment: Well, you need one more page of that note.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86570/explaining-the-method-of-characteristics

Comment: @user53076 Are these lecture notes available online? I am very interested by them :)

Answer (score 0):

As i understand it the main idea behind the Characteristic Method is to "transform" your PDE in a system of (infinite) ODE's.

However I think your lecture notes are missing the starting conditions:
$x(0,s) = f(s)$ and $y(0,s) = g(s)$ and $z(0,s) = h(s)$.

So each $s \in (\alpha,\beta)$ gives you one point on the initial curve $\gamma$:

$(x(0,s),y(0,s))
$

and thus $(x(t,s),y(t,s))$ is a curve which goes through that point in $\gamma$.

The key part is now that later one, you will discover that under certain assumptions $x(t,s)$, $y(t,s)$ and $z(t,s)$ solve a system of ODE's which is called the $\textit{Characterstic System}$. And in simple cases one can first solve the Characterstic System and then transform the solution to an $\textit{explicit}$ solution of the PDE.

Answer (score -3):

To clarify what your notes imply, the curve ${\cal C}_s$ contains points $(x(t;s),y(t;s),z(t;s))$ defined by solving the ODE $\frac{d}{dt}(x,y,z)=(a(x,y,z),b(x,y,z),c(x,y,z))$ for $-\varepsilon_s<t<\varepsilon_s$, and condition $(x(0;s),y(0;s),z(0;s))=(f(s),g(s),h(s))$ on $\Gamma$ at $t=0$.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1338464)

Comment: My revised comment answers "How does Cs 'start' on the initial curve if there is no f(s) or g(s) in the equation for Cs? What does x(t;s) mean" asked by OP.

Comment: After posting my answer, I discovered a similar, more complete answer in [Miersemann's lecture notes](https://www.math.uni-leipzig.de/~miersemann/pdebook.pdf) section 2.2.2.