# Where can I find these lectures notes? - Method of characteristics

Tags: reference-request

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282913/i-dont-understand-the-idea-behind-the-method-of-characteristics), the OP inserted parts of his lecture notes on the method of characteristics. Are they available online? Are they part of a book? I've searched the internet but I could not find anything. Where can I find them?

Comment: My best google searches have produced no results.  Let's hope someone else can find them.

Comment: Why not post a comment on that thread for its author.

Comment: I did not have enough reputation point (50) before asking this question. I see now I have :p EDIT : He will probably not answer. His profile says he last connected in 2014 :/

Comment: In that case, you should fight that compulsive thought of finding it and just use another reference ;)