# Intuition behind the method of characteristics

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have learnt the method of characteristics in a past PDE course, but it has always been taught as a sort of sequence of steps which lead to a solution. This has always bothered me and I would like to understand the geometric picture behind the method and some of the consequences that follow (i.e. how and what it means by a solution propagating along characteristics).

I have tried going through a few resources including books by Strauss and Evans, lecture notes such as [this one by Stanford](https://web.stanford.edu/class/math220a/handouts/firstorder.pdf), and other posts on this website ([Explaining the method of characteristics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86570/explaining-the-method-of-characteristics)). Despite all this something is still not clicking intuitively.

Here is what I have understood so far, let's take the following PDE as an example:
$$a(x,y) u_x + b(x,y)u_y = c(x,y)$$
We first observe that the PDE can be written as
$$\bigl \langle a(x,y), b(x,y), c(x,y)\bigr\rangle \cdot \bigl \langle u_x, u_y, -1 \bigr\rangle = 0$$
which tells us that the vector $V = \bigl \langle a(x,y), b(x,y), c(x,y)\bigr\rangle$ must lie in the tangent plane to the graph/surface $S = \{(x,y,u(x,y))\}$. Hence we would like to determine $S$ such that for each point $(x,y,z) \in S$, its tangent plane contains the vector $V$.

This amounts to to finding a curve $\mathcal{C}$ which lies in $S$. We parametrize $\mathcal{C}$ by a variable $s$, so that the tangent vector $V$ is now
$$V_s = \bigl \langle a\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr), b\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr), c\bigl(x(s),y(s)\bigr)\bigr\rangle$$

Thus the curve $\mathcal{C} = \{(x(s), y(s), z(s))\}$ results in the following system of ODEs:
$$\frac{dx}{ds} = a\bigl(x(s), y(s)\bigr)\\
\frac{dy}{ds} = b\bigl(x(s), y(s)\bigr)\\
\frac{dz}{ds} = c\bigl(x(s), y(s)\bigr)$$

We finally obtain our characteristic curves by solving the above system of equations. Taking the union of all the resulting characteristic curves results in a solution surface for our original PDE.

Somehow, after solving a first-order PDE using this method, for example taking the transport equation, it becomes apparent that $z(x,t)$ is constant along the lines $x-at = x_0$ but how? Furthermore, how does this imply that $u(x,t) = z(x,t) = f(x-at)$?

My questions:

- Why do we parametrize the curve $\mathcal{C}$ to begin with?
- What does it mean that characteristic curves propagate discontinuities or solutions? How does one infer this from this picture?
- I am still unclear what these curves are ultimately telling us. Does it tell us the "path" that some Cauchy data travels in the $xyz$ plane?
- Are there any mistakes in my understanding?
- The definition of $S$ seems to come out of nowhere, what is the motivation behind using such a surface?

Comment: You could also just start with inserting any differentiable curve into $u$, $z(s)=u(x(s),y(s))$, and consider its derivative $\dot z=u_x\dot x+u_y\dot y$. Now if you select the curve to have $\dot x=a$ and $\dot y=b$, then $\dot z=c$ follows. What you describe is a "higher order" geometric interpretation of this calculation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks, your comment helped me realize that in my description $z(x,y) = u(x,y)$ by comparing the vectors in the graph $S$ and the curve $\mathcal{C}$. What is still unclear however is for some given Cauchy data $f$, why is it that $z = f(x-at)$? Further, what does it mean that information propagates via these characteristic curves?